# Always get 20 even more than 20 files uploaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

THis is my problem illustration code ! My real project is want to do multiple upload files but not exceeding 24 files at one time upload . 
**But my problem is that file uploading was only send 20 files at once even more than 20 files are uploaded** I want to 21 if I uploaded 21 files ,if 22 get 22 ...and so on ! How can I handle this ?

```
<form action="sessions.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"> 
<ul id="attachment_list">
<li><input type="file" name="attachments[]" class="carte-attachment" multiple></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#attachment_list").on("change",".carte-attachment",function(){
 $('#attachment_list').append('<li><input type="file" name="attachments[]" class="carte-attachment" multiple></li>');
});
</script>
```

**sessions.php**

```
<?php
var_dump(count($_FILES["attachments"]["name"]);   //always print 20  even more than 20 files
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a limit added to the maximum number of allowed files to upload in order to secure servers from attacks such as DOS.

Though, there is a directive you can set in order to increase the maximum allowed number of files (which is 20 by default) : `max_file_uploads` directive

> Added "max_file_uploads" INI directive, which can be set to limit the
>   number of file uploads per-request to 20 by default, to prevent
>   possible DOS via temporary file exhaustion. (Ilia) (changelog for PHP
>   5.3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Theres default file upload limit set for php which you may find in php.ini file. configuration with name `max_file_uploads` change it as per your need, by default it set to 20